# Displaying multiple figures with differents colors

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a matlab code that generates `3D` points , so I want to plot each 3D point with different colors.

My last code for generat all points are

```
figure(i),plot3(mx,my,mz,'r*');
```

and this one plot all peaks but with same color which are red.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtMae.jpg    whene i use    figure(i),plot3(mx,my,mz,'b*');  and i want to display all figure with specefic cokor

Answer (score 3):

instead of `figure(i),plot3(mx,my,mz,'r*');` you can plot each datapoint separately and assign a different color using the property 'Color' of the plot3.

such an example would be:

```
figure(i),hold on
for j=1:length(mx)
plot3(mx(j),my(j),mz(j),'Color',rand(1,3));
end
hold off
```

The way each point is coloured is up to you just change the rand to something that makes sense.

Comment: @user3685182: ASantosRibeiro's solution works.  I don't understand what further problem you have.

Comment: i want to display each figure with different colore map as u see the prev image   show  figure 5 and 6 with same color i want a different color for each figure

Comment: @user3685182: This wasn't in your original post.  You need to update your question so you don't mislead us.

Answer (score 1):

What about using e.g. `hsv`:

```
M = length(mx);
cols = hsv(M); % specify M colors by hsv
figure(i);
hold on;

for pIdx = 1:M
    plot3(mx(pIdx),my(pIdx),mz(pIdx),'Color',cols(pIdx,:));
end
```

Comment: +1. Not bad! You could even substitute the HSV call for any `colormap`

Comment: ColoursToUse=['r' 'b' 'g' 'c']
figure(1)
hold on
for i=1:4
plot3(mx(i), my(i), mz(i), strcat(ColoursToUse(i),'o'))
end                 but it show :Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Comment: ColoursToUse=['r' 'b' 'g' 'c']
figure(1)
hold on
for i=1:4
plot3(mx(i), my(i), mz(i), strcat(ColoursToUse(i),'o'))
end



Index exceeds matrix dimensions.